# Laravel 4.2 going to the wrong route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes, laravel-routing

This is the url I am accessing : http://example.com/hotel/expired

instead to go at the good controller for this route

```
Route::get('/hotel/expired', ModuleLoader::load_controller(_ACCOUNT , 'redirectExpired'));
```

This is the route used :

```
Route::post('/hotel/search', 'HotelControllerB2C@search');
```

However, if I change my /hotel/expired route for this /hotel/session/expired , the right controller will be used

```
Route::any('/hotel/search/{dep_date}/{dep_code}/{ret_date}/{ages}', 'HotelControllerB2C@showSearch');
Route::any('/hotel/search/{dep_date}/{dep_code}/{ret_date}/{ages}/{property_type}', 'HotelControllerB2C@showSearch');
Route::post('/hotel/search', 'HotelControllerB2C@search');
Route::get('/hotel/detail/{index}', 'HotelControllerB2C@showDetail');
Route::post('/hotel/detail', 'HotelControllerB2C@detail');
Route::get('/hotel/{sid}', ModuleLoader::load_controller(_ACCOUNT , 'showPreviousSearch'));
Route::any('/hotel/confirmation/{url}', ModuleLoader::load_controller(_ACCOUNT , 'confirmation'));
Route::get('/hotel/expired', ModuleLoader::load_controller(_ACCOUNT , 'redirectExpired'));
```

why laravel think /hotel/expired is /hotel/search ? one use post method and the other one use get ...

Comment: Try placing the route /hotel/expired before /hotel/{sid}, and also using regex to specifiy that the route parameters shouldn't be empty

Answer (score 0):

Routes in Larval are resolved in order you define. You have `/hotel/{sid}` and `/hotel/expired` after that, so in that case:

```
/hotel/anything => goes to /hotel/{sid} route
/hotel/expired => also goes to /hotel/{sid} route
```

To avoid this, you should first define most specific route and then more general, so in your case you should put line:

```
Route::get('/hotel/expired', ModuleLoader::load_controller(_ACCOUNT , 'redirectExpired'));
```

before

```
Route::get('/hotel/{sid}', ModuleLoader::load_controller(_ACCOUNT , 'showPreviousSearch'));
```